# Capture frame in direct mode (Nvidia)

Tags: directx, video-capture, oculus, nvapi, openvr

I need to capture frame from application that runs in direct mode into D3D11Texture2D. I was performing that by hooking *Present()* or *Present1()* commonly, but now some apps (e.g. SteamVR games, OVR games etc) output frames in [direct mode](https://developer.nvidia.com/vrworks) ([Nvidia and AMD opened this feature for VR](http://www.roadtovr.com/new-nvidia-and-amd-drivers-unlock-direct-driver-mode-for-oculus-rift-users/)).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you should hook the DX12 device.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but there is no Present1() calls and there is no access to swapchain at all. Direct mode gives interface to handle driver-level output and I don't know how to capture the frame texture.

Comment: Can you try FRAPS to see if it could capture the frames? If it can then there is a way and I'll try to help you further with it.

Comment: Maybe you should try hooking CreateSwapChainForHwnd and take the swapchain's buffer periodically or also hook other methods like ID3D12Fence Signal or SetEventOnCompletion and take the swapchain's backbuffer inside them.

Comment: You can also hook ID3D12GraphicsCommandList methods, like Close or ResourceBarrier to get the render target from there.

Comment: There is no swapchain access. If app uses Direct Mode, it pushes data directly to frontbuffer, but thanks, I'll try hooking ResourceBarrier.

Comment: Maybe you need to hook both ResourceBarrier and Close. You can take the render target in the call of ResourceBarrier and then copy the buffer in the call of Close. I'll be curious to know if it works when you test it.

Comment: I handled it. I obtained `ID3D11Device` and `ID3D11Context` and caughts render targets. I explored original process' API calls and discovered lots of variants on *OM* stage. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I dove into *Output-Merger stage* in graphics pipeline. I found that all I need is in **render target**(s). Multiple render targets are possible to implement multi-buffering.